# Which of the below is my CPU temperature

Tags: linux, command-line, temperature

**Goal**

Measure the CPU temperature of my Linux Box.

**Work done till now**

I have installed lm-sensors to detect the temperature and below is the output of the command sensor:

```
root@XXXX-XX :# sensors

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +66.0°C  (crit = +255.0°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +65.4°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +100.0°C, hyst = +99.0°C)

radeon-pci-0008
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +64.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:            N/A  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)
```

The output of the cat /proc/cpuinfo is:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 16
model name  : AMD A8-4500M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x6001116
cpu MHz     : 1400.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 16
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
.
.
.

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 16
model name  : AMD A8-4500M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics   
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x6001116
cpu MHz     : 1400.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 17
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes


processor   : 2
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 16
model name  : AMD A8-4500M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics   
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x6001116
cpu MHz     : 1400.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 18
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes


processor   : 3
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 16
model name  : AMD A8-4500M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics   
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x6001116
cpu MHz     : 1400.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 19
initial apicid  : 3
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
```

**Question**

Out of the above readings from command sensor and cat /proc/cpuinfo, I am not sure which is  exactly **my  cpu temperature** in the output of sensors and what is the one to one relation between the output of both the commands (ie: which field (ie:output of sensor) matches with the field of cat /proc/cpuinfo).

Comment: Has your question been answered ? In yes it is good practice to accept an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cpu temperature is shown by the k10 sensor, but beware it is assumed to be inaccurate.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/hwmon/k10temp